# Exchange Mailbox Losing Contacts

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, mailbox, contacts

I am currently running into an issue where a user's contacts within Exchange are losing details every couple of months.

We keep having to restore the user's contacts from Backup to fix the issue. The user is using an iPhone and I have seen in the past from different web searches that some iPhone users have had their contacts deleted by their phones. I am having trouble narrowing down exactly what would be causing it however.

The user is using the default mail app and the Exchange server is running 2007.

Has anyone else run into this issue previous and been able to track down exactly what is causing it?

Comment: Keep noted that [Exchange 2007 is EOL since 2017-04-11](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Exchange-2007-End-of-Life-Roadmap-c3024358-326b-404e-9fe6-b618e54d977d). You do no longer get any security updates or patches. it is time to [migrate to a newer version from Exchange](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/206-migrate-from-exchange-2010-to-exchange-2016.html). It isn´t that complicated.

Comment: @BastianW Haha, out of support since yesterday.

Comment: @blaughw yes, its now really time to move to a newer version. If the server will crash nobody from Microsoft will touch and try to fix it. I would say that a migration is not business critical.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't sound like a real solution but I would seriously consider updating your Exchange server. Already with Exchange 2010 and some recent CU updates I have found mobile connections (and certainly iPhones) to give a lot of headaches. If that's not an option try to let the user use another app.